# Customizing iOS Switch Toggle

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Feel like I'm missing something super obvious. But for the iPhone Default Switch is there a way to add text "On" "Off" for the different states?

I only see how to edit the tint color in the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISwitch.html

I'm trying to do something like this:
http://cl.ly/image/062n0B3r1q0M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 7, switches no longer support text or custom images. As you mentioned, color tinting is really the only configuration option for them. `onImage` and `offImage` properties still exist in the API, but they have no effect.

Comment: No problem... If you really need that functionality, google for "ios 7 custom switch control" - there are open source options out there.